# python and distance calculation

Tags: python

I'm a rookie one , so sorry for this rudimentary questions I wanted to challenge my self asking some basic questions and write it in python . but cannot integrate all I've learned

I just wanted a program to receive 2 data points ( 5 dimensions) and then calculate the Euclidean ,Manhattan and Malinowski distance. I wrote this basic form but it breaks

---

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

data_set_1 = input ('enter the first 5 data set')
data_set_2 = input ('enter the second 5 data set')
euclidean_distance = distance.euclidean(data_set_1, data_set_2)
print('Euclidean Distance b/w', point_1, 'and', point_2, 'is: ', euclidean_distance)
```

---

Question#1 : where is the problem in this code?
Questions#2 : How can I force the user to enter the 5 dimensions tuple? cannot understand how to loop over and check the length

any comments would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: How can we know there is a problem? Without some error message or some failed execution it is difficult to know.

Comment: Like @fernand0 pointed out, please add the error message you receive to the question. Additionally, take a look at the documentation of [scipy.spatial.distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html#scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean) and the example provided. Note that the arguments are of variable type `list` and not `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not clear from the description.
I have demonstrating two ways, one to take input as comma separated (as text) and covert it to numbers.

The second is to use ast.literal_eval (in case the input is structured).

[The code lacks full validations]

cat x.py

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
import ast

data_set_1 = input ('enter the first 5 data set: ')
data_set_2 = input ('enter the second 5 data set: ')

# I am assuming user just entered comma separated numbers
# this is still a string, convert it to a list

ds1 = data_set_1.split(",")
ds2 = data_set_2.split(",")

# these are still list of strings, convert to list of ints
ds1 = [int(x) for x in ds1]
ds2 = [int(x) for x in ds2]

euclidean_distance = distance.euclidean(ds1, ds2)
print('Euclidean Distance b/w {0} and {1} , is: {2} '.format(ds1, ds2, euclidean_distance))


# Let's see how the 5-D tuple works

# Remember, that you need to validate the user input, which I haven't done
fiveDtupleString = input("Enter 5-D duple: ")
fiveDtuple = ast.literal_eval(fiveDtupleString)
print("You Entered : {}".format(fiveDtuple))
```

python x.py

```
enter the first 5 data set: 1,2,3,4,5
enter the second 5 data set: 6,7,8,9,10
Euclidean Distance b/w [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] , is: 11.180339887498949
Enter 5-D duple: [(1,6), (2,7), (3,8), (4,9), (5,10)]
You Entered : [(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

flag = True
data_set_1, data_set_2 = None, None
while flag:
    data_set_1 = input('enter the first 5 data set').split()
    data_set_2 = input('enter the second 5 data set').split()
    flag = False if len(data_set_1) == len(data_set_2) == 5 else True

data_set_1 = [int(d) for d in data_set_1]
data_set_2 = [int(d) for d in data_set_2]

euclidean_distance = distance.euclidean(data_set_1, data_set_2)
print('Euclidean Distance b/w {0} and {1} , is: {2} '.format(data_set_1, data_set_2, euclidean_distance))
```

Sample İnput:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

and

```
6 7 8 9 10
```

Output:

```
Euclidean Distance b/w [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] , is: 11.180339887498949
```

Q.1 = input gives str, you should convert it to int

Q.2 = Get input with white space and split it by white space then check len of lists if the are equal to 5 or not